# using laravel 4.2 to check the team formation

Tags: php, laravel

I am going to build a fantasy cricket site.To make the site i have to validate a lot of things.most of the validation i have done already.I got stuck on the team formation validation.Like I have 7 team formation.Whenever user takes a player in his/her team i have to check is he/she taking player according to the formation.I built a logic already but the logic needs huge amounts of conditional statement.I just want to avoid huge amounts of conditional statement.If someone help me out how i can build the logic efficiently  it would be really appreciated.
[image: this is the team formation table]

Comment: would you explain more of what you want to achieve exactly, for some people like me do not know cricket. unless you're talking about the cricket who makes good sound at night ;)

Comment: Paste the current conditional statements

Answer (score 0):

According to your requirements what I've understood so far that you have 7 forms of team where 4 main categories in each team which are: `Batsman`, `Allrounder`, `Wicket Keeper` and `Bowler`. So you may create an array for each format for example:

```
$teamFormats = [
    'format1' => ['batsman' => 6, 'allrounder' => 0, 'keeper' => 1, 'bowler' => 4], 
    'format2' => ['batsman' => 5, 'allrounder' => 0, 'keeper' => 1, 'bowler' => 5],
    'format3' => [...],
    'format4' => [...],
    'format5' => [...],
    'format6' => [...],
    'format7' => ['batsman' => 4, 'allrounder' => 3, 'keeper' => 1, 'bowler' => 3],
];
```

Then, just grab the inputs and prepare an array using same format and compare the array values. Since each array is unique so it woll be easy enough to find out the exact format. For example:

```
$submittedTeam = '... Prepare the array...';
foreach($teamFormats as $formatName => $format) {
    if($submittedTeam == $format) {
      // Matching found...
      // $formatName would be one from format1 to format7
      break; // Use break to quit the loop
    }
}
```

You can keep the `$teamFormats` in a class as `protected $teamFormats` or create a config file and return the array. Hope you got the idea.